# Approximate x+1 without addition and logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, approximation

I am looking for an expression $f(x)$ involving only constants, $x$, multiplication, exponentiation, and division such that for in as large an interval [1,a) as possible, the function closely approximates $g(x)=x+1$. Or maybe even a recursive sequence of increasingly good approximations $f_i(x)$.

$f(x)$ **should not** include any addition and logarithms. Allowed operators are: $$ x^{n}, nx, \frac {x}{n}$$ where $n$ can be $x$ or $const$.  Any composition of these operators is  allowed. Here is something I tried ([graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd8ZD.png)):

$$ f(x) = 1.8 (x^{\frac{1}{2}}) (x^{\frac{1}{2*3}})^{(x\frac{1}{2*3})} (x^{\frac{1}{2*3*5}})^{{(x\frac{1}{2*3*5})}^{(x\frac{1}{2*3*5})}}
$$

But continuing this pattern does not make $f(x)$ any closer to $g(x)$.

Comment: What does "approximate" mean?  If you just want $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ then $f(x)=x$ works.

Comment: @lulu I want $f(x)$ to be as close as possible to $g(x)$ at least for some interval [1; a]. What you suggest wont work for me. (sorry for unclear description)

Comment: @JohnBrown So you are looking for an expression $f(x)$ involving only constants, $x$, multiplication, exponentiation, and division such that for in as large an interval $[1,a)$ as possible, the function closely approximates $g(x)=x+1$. Or maybe even a recursive sequence of increasingly good approximations $f_i(x)$.

Comment: @user326210 Yes, exactly! (again sorry for unclear problem description).

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It's interesting.

Comment: @JohnBrown Any such function would be of the form $\,u\, x^v\,$ for some constants $\,u,v\,$. Quantify what you mean by "*closely approximates*", then determine the $\,u,v\,$ which maximize that "*closeness*" on $\,[1,a)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv  my sense (possibly wrong) is that the OP wants to allow composition of these operations.  The given example involves things like $x^{ax}$ for instance.  Hard to get a handle on the space of allowed functions.

Comment: @dxiv could you please clarify why this function will be $ ux^{v} $, but not $ ux^{ax^v} $ or something else?

Comment: @lulu Yes, composition is allowed. I will include this in description. Thank you.

Comment: @lulu I assumed $\,n\,$ to be a constant in those `allowed operators`, in which case you'd never get $\,x^{ax}\,$. At the same time, yes, I agree that that's probably not what the OP meant, so waiting for clarifications.

Comment: @dxiv $n$ is constant. Composition of operators is allowed.

Comment: @JohnBrown If $\,n\,$ is a constant then how do you get $\,x^{ax}\,$ by composition?

Comment: @dxiv You are right. Corrected description. $n$ can be $x$.

Comment: @JohnBrown OK, better now. Still a rather odd problem, though.

Comment: A really boring example is $x\exp(\frac1{x})\cdot \exp(-\frac1{2x^2})\cdot \exp(\frac1{3x^3})\cdot \exp(-\frac1{4x^4})\cdots \exp(\frac1{(2n+1)x^{2n+1}})\cdot\exp(\frac1{(2n+2)x^{2n+2}})$ where $\exp(x)=e^x$ if you allow $e^x$ which consist of constants and exponentiation.

Comment: @dxiv I've been thinking about this for at least 4 days now. I have no idea how to approach it, other than computer bruteforce or intuition+grapher (which I already tried). That's why I posted it here.

Comment: $$f(x)=2x^{0.5971x^{0.085}}$$ is not too bad on $[1,50]$. For different upper limits, both the $0.5971$ and $0.085$ can be adjusted for still-reasonable approximations.

Comment: @kingW3 Your answer meats all criteria and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Included your answer in problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand the question, you're allowed to do the following:

1. Take $f(x)^{g(x)}$, if $f$ and $g$ are allowed functions
2. Take $f(x)g(x)$, if $f$ and $g$ are allowed functions
3. Take $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, if $f$ and $g$ are allowed functions

(starting with the base allowed functions of constants and $f_0(x)=x$). With this, one can express

$$e^{f(x)}=\frac{(ex)^{f(x)}}{x^{f(x)}}.$$

Thus, we can use the technique of kingW3 and approximate

$$x+1=\exp\left(\ln(x+1)\right)\approx x\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{nx^n}\right)=x\prod_{n=1}^N \exp\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{nx^n}\right).$$

As this is simply the product of allowed functions (as $\exp(f(x))$ is an allowed function where $f(x)$ is), this is also allowed.

Comment: Nice! And the more terms you include, the more accurate the approximation. The approximation is most accurate for smaller values, I think.

Comment: @user326210 Thanks, and thank you for the edit.